# SQL : how to check if all entries of a table are in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to make a program where users enter what ingredients they have in their home, and the system gives recipes that they can make with using only those ingredients.

Table of ingredients that are needed to make recipes.
'recipe_ingredients'

```
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| curr_recipe_id | ingredient_id | ingredient_name |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|              1 |             1 | ingredient 1    |
|              1 |             2 | ingredient 2    |
|              1 |             3 | ingredient 3    |
|              1 |             4 | ingredient 4    |
|              2 |             5 | ingredient 5    |
|              2 |             6 | ingredient 6    |
|              2 |             7 | ingredient 7    |
|              2 |             8 | ingredient 4    |
|              2 |             9 | ingredient 2    |
|              2 |            10 | ingredient 8    |
|              2 |            11 | ingredient 9    |
|              2 |            12 | ingredient 10   |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Table of recipes

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| recipe_id | name                 |
+-----------+----------------------+
|         1 | recipe 1             |
|         2 | recipe 2             |
+-----------+----------------------+
```

Table of ingredients at home:
'home_ing'

```
+---------------+
| home_ing_name |
+---------------+
| ingredient 1  |
| ingredient 2  |
| ingredient 3  |
| ingredient 4  |
+---------------+
```

I want to get all the recipes that I can make using the ingredients that I have in home.

What I should get as output:

Table of possible recipes with ingredients at home:

```
+----------------+
| recipe id      |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

I have tried using this query:

```
select * 
from recipes
where recipe_id in (select curr_recipe_id 
                    from recipe_ingredients 
                    where ingredient_name) in (select home_ing_name from home_ing));
```

This query returns:

```
+----------------+
| recipe id      |
+----------------+
|              1 |
|              2 |
+----------------+
```

because my ingredients at home table contains one of the ingredients of recipe 2.

Comment: what have you tried? and why did that fail ?

Comment: You've tagged [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysqli]] here; what RDBMS are you really using? mysqli is an PHP driver for MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: i have tried this:              
 select * from breakfast_recipes where 
               recipe_id in (
                  select curr_recipe_id from breakfast_recipe_ingredients where
                   ingredient_name) in (select home_ing_name from home_ing)); 
   
but it gives me the 'recipe 1' and 'recipe 2' because i have one ingredient of the 'recipe 2' in my 'ingredients at home' table.

Comment: [Edit] your question, @MustafaCeylan  with your attempts please.

Comment: ok i am editing

Comment: How can you use  tables (`breakfast_recipes` and `breakfast_recipe_ingredients`) that are not included in your question? How would anyone be able to help you if you do not share enough info ?

Comment: Joining on the Ingredient name seems like a bad idea; you should have an ingredient table, and then the `HomeIngredient` and `RecipeIngredient` Tables should have a foreign key relationship to it using the relevant ID.

Comment: Why not simply setup a fiddle according to your data, share the link and thus allow people to replicate your problem?

Comment: sory, breakfast_recipes and breakfast_recipe_ingredients tables were in the question but i forgot to change the names in my query,  i have corrected it. is the question clear now?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   recipe_id,
   name
FROM recipe
WHERE recipe_id NOT IN (
   SELECT recipe_id
   FROM recipe_ingredients ri
   LEFT JOIN home_ing h ON h.home_ing_name = ri.ingredient_name
   WHERE home_ing_name IS NULL)
```

This SQL is listing all recipes without (`NOT IN`) unmatching ingredients. The sub-query will find recipes which has non-existing home_ingredients needed for the recipe.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da46e6dc9845beb7a9fafe3e14e549ea)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
Select recepi_id, MIN(HaveIngredient) from(
Select IR.recepi_id, Case when IH.home_ing_name is null then 0 else 1 end as HaveIngredient
from tableOfInredients IR
Left join tableOfIngredientsAtHome IH 
on IR.Ingredient_Name = IH.Home_ing_name) tmp
group by recepi_id
having MIN(HaveIngredient) = 1
```

First step here is I'm joining receipt list with ingredients I have. If I have ingredient I will mark as 1 if not 0.

Then I just want to have one row per recepi and I select recepi_Id with MIN value of HaveIngredient value. In having clause I select just the recepies where all ingredients is at home.

Comment: I think this will select recipes where you have minimal 1 ingredient at home, and not necessarily **ALL** ingredients.

Comment: No, or that's not my intention at least. It will give first one row per ingredient in recepi list. With 0 for ingredients you miss and 1 for those you have. When you then select min it will show 0 if you miss one ingredient or more. It will give 1 if all items is in place.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: it works as intended, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This query gets all the recipe_ingredient records which *aren't met* by the ingredients provided in the input, and from that gets all the recipes that aren't in that list.

```sql
SELECT r.recipe_id
FROM recipe r
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient ri   
   WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
   AND NOT EXISTS(
       /* making the assumption here that the list of ingredients you have is provided
          in some form of input that can be placed in temp table or similar */
       SELECT * FROM #my_ingredients mi
       WHERE mi.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
   )
)
```

The main difference here from the other approach is that it'll return recipes that don't have *any* ingredients, which depending on your requirements may or may not be desirable.